# How to build on remote Docker server with Jenkins declarative pipeline?

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I wrote a declarative pipeline within Jenkins. This pipeline should run in a Docker container on a remote Docker server.

I read [Customizing the execution environment](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/#execution-environment):

> **Customizing the execution environment**
>
> Pipeline is designed to easily use Docker images as the execution environment for a single Stage or the entire Pipeline. Meaning that a user can define the tools required for their Pipeline, without having to manually configure agents. Practically any tool which can be packaged in a Docker container. can be used with ease by making only minor edits to a Jenkinsfile.
>
> ```
> pipeline {
>     agent {
>         docker { image 'node:7-alpine' }
>     }
>     stages {
>         stage('Test') {
>             steps {
>                 sh 'node --version'
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

and it works, but it uses Jenkins server as Docker server.

I read [Using a remote Docker server](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/#using-a-remote-docker-server):

> **Using a remote Docker server**
>
> By default, the Docker Pipeline plugin will communicate with a local Docker daemon, typically accessed through /var/run/docker.sock.
>
> To select a non-default Docker server, such as with Docker Swarm, the withServer() method should be used.
>
> By passing a URI, and optionally the Credentials ID of a Docker Server Certificate Authentication pre-configured in Jenkins, to the method with:
>
> ```
> node {
>     checkout scm
>
>     docker.withServer('tcp://swarm.example.com:2376', 'swarm-certs') {
>         docker.image('mysql:5').withRun('-p 3306:3306') {
>             /* do things */
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

and this works, but it uses scripted pipeline.

I also read [Specifying a Docker Label](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/#specifying-a-docker-label):

> **Specifying a Docker Label**
>
> By default, Pipeline assumes that any configured agent is capable of running Docker-based Pipelines. For Jenkins environments which have macOS, Windows, or other agents, which are unable to run the Docker daemon, this default setting may be problematic. Pipeline provides a global option in the Manage Jenkins page, and on the Folder level, for specifying which agents (by Label) to use for running Docker-based Pipelines.

but using a label would need a full Jenkins slave with sshd and a Jenkins user installed, online all the time and Jenkins's master would install slave libraries. That sounds a little bit heavy just for using declarative pipelines instead of scripted pipelines.

How could I build on a remote Docker server with a declarative pipeline?

Answer (score 4):

I think you mix few things here. In regards to [documentation's part about the agent](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#agent), agent part is used to identify the node your stage should be run on, along with special configuration and information.

Docker tag is in turn giving the information that it should be run from inside the image.

This doesn't leave you any room for connecting to external docker server unless you would make it a Jenkins node with some special label, like for example 'docker-special'. Then you could do just as simple stuff as

```
agent {
    docker {
        image 'maven:3-alpine'
        label 'docker-special'
    }
}
```

Documentation part on docker's label

> **docker**
>
> Execute the Pipeline, or stage, with the given container which will be
>   dynamically provisioned on a node pre-configured to accept
>   Docker-based Pipelines, or on a node matching the optionally defined
>   label parameter.

As for your particular use case.

This part of jenkins [documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/), mentions the sidecar pattern/advanced usage, and they immediately switch to scripted.

So yes as I've mentioned it, this is not available in declarative. The only way out for declarative would be to mark the external server as jenkins node with specific label.

Comment: Unfortunately it is no way out of my problem, because I can't use the docker host as an build slave/node. The build slave/node solution I already knew, that's the reason, I ask the question at SO. Then I have to use scripted pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a 'full Jenkins slave' - you just need a machine that runs Docker and that serves the docker socket over TCP/TLS with x509 client auth; DO NOT serve unauthenticated and unencrypted or you'll open a planet-sized hole in your security perimeter (and its an opportunity to learn openssl! ;)

For declarative you can use 'node' inside the agent tag and configure the template with a docker container (that has everything Jenkins needs) associated by the label.

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        node {
            label 'docker-agent'
        }
    }
    ...
```

You'll need to mount the docker socket (and your agent workspace) or you won't be able to do very much from inside the agent container.

Answer (score 0):

I figure out a way to make it work with declarative pipeline.

According to [How to Connect to a Remote Docker Daemon](https://dockerlabs.collabnix.com/beginners/components/daemon/access-daemon-externally.html), docker CLI only needs an environmental variable `DOCKER_HOST` to specify the remote docker server uri. So I tried to add it to the beginning of my declarative pipeline script, like this:

```
env.DOCKER_HOST = 'tcp://<docker_server_ip>:<port>'

pipeline {
...
```

It works!